How can I dynamically swap out Python’s built-in functions in an imported module for testing purposes, without altering the source code?
I am working on testing a legacy Python module that relies heavily on built-in functions like print(), len(), and others, but I don’t want to modify the module's source code directly. The goal is to dynamically replace these built-ins with mock implementations to simulate certain behaviors during testing (for example, replacing print() to capture printed output).
I'm aware of the unittest.mock module and how it works for mocking functions in a specific scope, but I'm struggling to figure out how to intercept built-ins for an imported module without changing that module itself.
def legacy_function():
    print("This is a legacy function")
    return len([1, 2, 3])

I want to mock print() and len() only in the context of legacy_function() when I run my tests, but without altering the legacy_module.py file itself.
Things I’ve tried:

Using unittest.mock.patch() on the built-ins for legacy_function, but it seems to affect the entire environment rather than just that function.
Swapping out built-ins in the global scope, but this also leads to unpredictable side effects.

Is there a way to mock built-ins only within the scope of a specific function in an imported module, dynamically during runtime, without modifying the module's source?

Could you please provide your try with unittest.mock.patch() that seems wrong for you

To mock print() and len() specifically within the scope of a single function during testing without modifying the source code of the module, you can use unittest.mock.patch(). The key here is to target the built-ins of the module where the function is defined, rather than globally.
Here's the code
# legacy_module.py
def legacy_function():
    print("This is a legacy function")
    return len([1, 2, 3])

# tests.py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import legacy_module

class TestLegacyFunction(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('legacy_module.print')  # Mock 'print' only in 'legacy_module'
    @patch('legacy_module.len')    # Mock 'len' only in 'legacy_module'
    def test_legacy_function(self, mock_len, mock_print):
        # Change the print output
        def custom_print(value):
            # Replace the original print value with a custom message
            new_value = f"Modified print: {value}"
            return new_value
        
        # Set mock_print to use custom_print
        mock_print.side_effect = custom_print
        
        # Mock len() behavior
        mock_len.return_value = 99  # Return a mocked value for len

        # Call the function to test
        result = legacy_module.legacy_function()

        # Assertions
        mock_print.assert_called_once_with("This is a legacy function")  # Ensure print() is called correctly
        self.assertEqual(mock_print.call_args[0][0], "This is a legacy function")  # Check what was passed to print
        self.assertEqual(result, 99)  # Check the mocked return value of len()

        # Test that the modified print works
        print_output = mock_print("Test")
        self.assertEqual(print_output, "Modified print: Test")  # Confirm the modified print value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

I hope this will help you a little.
